# ¿Cómo le hago en mi codigo para hacer que cuando el usuario le de click al boton me aparezca el mensaje que diga cual es su edad pero abajo de todo?

Tags: javascript, html

Soy algo nuevo en esto y estoy tratando de aprender. Agradecería mucho si me explicaran porque al darle click al boton aparece el mensaje de su edad pero en otra parte. Yo lo que quiero es que me aparezca pero abajo de lo que viene en el HTML.

```js
var añoActual = 2021;
var edad;
var datoUsuario = document.getElementById("datoAñoNacimiento");
var boton = document.getElementById("botoncito");
boton.addEventListener("click", edadActual);

function edadActual() {
  datoUsuario = parseInt(datoUsuario.value);
  edad = añoActual - datoUsuario;
  document.write("Tu edad es de " + edad + " años.");
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>¿Cuál es tu edad?</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>
    Bienvenido usuario!!
  </h1>
  <h4>
    Para saber su edad ingrese lo que se le solicite.
  </h4>
  <p>¿Cuál es tu año de nacimiento?
    <input type="text" id="datoAñoNacimiento" />
    <input type="button" value="click" id="botoncito" />
  </p>
  <script src="edad.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Aunque sé que no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta, evita `document.write`, ya que en algunos casos puede entrar en conflicto con una extensión instalada y también usar este método es considerado una mala práctica en SEO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que `document` hace referencia  TODO tu HTML, entonces cuando haces `document.write` estas reescribiendo todo tu HTML y se reemplaza lo que ya tienes, una solución sería crear un espacio vacío con un `id` específico el cual vas a rellenar con la nueva información.

```js
var añoActual = 2021;
var edad;
var datoUsuario = document.getElementById("datoAñoNacimiento");
var boton = document.getElementById("botoncito");
var contenedorEdad = document.getElementById("edad");
boton.addEventListener("click", edadActual);

function edadActual() {
  datoUsuario = parseInt(datoUsuario.value);
  edad = añoActual - datoUsuario;
  contenedorEdad.innerText = "Tu edad es de " + edad + " años.";
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>¿Cuál es tu edad?</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>
    Bienvenido usuario!!
  </h1>
  <h4>
    Para saber su edad ingrese lo que se le solicite.
  </h4>
  <p>¿Cuál es tu año de nacimiento?
    <input type="text" id="datoAñoNacimiento" />
    <input type="button" value="click" id="botoncito" />
  </p>
  <p id="edad"> </p>
  <script src="edad.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

En este caso creo un nuevo elemento de tipo `p` vacío, el cuál tiene el id `edad`, guardo su referencia en una variable llamada `contenedorEdad` y edito su texto interno con el atributo `innerText` del mismo. Otra posible solución es crear el elemento con los datos que necesitas y luego añadirlo a tu HTML.

Por cierto, date una vuelta por [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y obtén tu primera medalla!

Comment: wow gracias encerio. Lo voy a checar :)

Comment: La mejor manera de dar las gracias en SO es marcar la respuesta como aceptada, @EdsonEduardoSánchezAlvarez! No solo recompensas al autor de la respuesta con 15 de reputación, si no que también haces que la respuesta sea más visible para otras personas que puedan tener una duda similar.